# Average every duplicated column for each row?

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have the following dataframe.

```
temp = structure(list(A = c(0, 0, 0, 3.72900887033786, 1.94860084749336, 
0), C = c(0, 0, 0, 3.44095219802964, 2.35049724708413, 0.0285691521967709
), A = c(0, 0, 0, 3.29572302453997, 0.933572638261024, 0), D = c(0, 
0, 0, 2.4905701304462, 1.54101915313356, 0), E = c(0, 0, 0, 4.23189316164533, 
1.7311832415722, 0), E = c(0, 0, 0, 4.37851162325373, 2.50080205305716, 
0), D = c(0, 0, 0, 3.68929916053589, 2.4905701304462, 0.189033824390017
), F = c(0, 2.27500704749987, 0, 3.68032435684402, 1.77820857639809, 
0), A = c(0, 0, 0, 3.5668151540109, 1.72683121703249, 0.0285691521967709
), G = c(0, 0, 0, 5.6450098843911, 3.09929520433778, 0)), row.names = c("5_8S_rRNA", 
"5S_rRNA", "7SK", "A1BG", "A1BG-AS1", "A1CF"), class = "data.frame")
```

It looks like this.

```
                 A          C         A        D        E        E         D        F          A        G
5_8S_rRNA 0.000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.0000000 0.000000 0.00000000 0.000000
5S_rRNA   0.000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.0000000 2.275007 0.00000000 0.000000
7SK       0.000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.0000000 0.000000 0.00000000 0.000000
A1BG      3.729009 3.44095220 3.2957230 2.490570 4.231893 4.378512 3.6892992 3.680324 3.56681515 5.645010
A1BG-AS1  1.948601 2.35049725 0.9335726 1.541019 1.731183 2.500802 2.4905701 1.778209 1.72683122 3.099295
A1CF      0.000000 0.02856915 0.0000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.1890338 0.000000 0.02856915 0.000000
```

What I'd like to do is collapse any column that are duplicates by averaging duplicates, but I want to do this for each row.

The ideal dataframe would contain the same amount of rows, but would only contain columns A, C, D, E, F, G. Is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We could use `split.default` to split by the column names and loop over the `list`, apply the `rowMeans`

```
 sapply(split.default(temp, names(temp)), rowMeans)
                    A          C          D        E        F        G
5_8S_rRNA 0.000000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
5S_rRNA   0.000000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.000000 2.275007 0.000000
7SK       0.000000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
A1BG      3.530515683 3.44095220 3.08993465 4.305202 3.680324 5.645010
A1BG-AS1  1.536334901 2.35049725 2.01579464 2.115993 1.778209 3.099295
A1CF      0.009523051 0.02856915 0.09451691 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
```

Answer (score 7):

Another base R solution with `rowsum`:

```r
t(rowsum(t(temp), names(temp)) / c(table(names(temp))))

                    A          C          D        E        F        G
5_8S_rRNA 0.000000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
5S_rRNA   0.000000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.000000 2.275007 0.000000
7SK       0.000000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
A1BG      3.530515683 3.44095220 3.08993465 4.305202 3.680324 5.645010
A1BG-AS1  1.536334901 2.35049725 2.01579464 2.115993 1.778209 3.099295
A1CF      0.009523051 0.02856915 0.09451691 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is a base R solution:

```
t(do.call(rbind, by(t(temp), row.names(t(temp)), FUN = colMeans)))
```

Or with **tidyverse**

Here is a `tidyverse` option, where we can split on the unique names, then we set the names for each dataframe, then use `rowMeans`. However, we have to use `setNames` in the first `map` statement to make the column names unique, as `tidyverse` does not like duplicate column names. Then, since the rownames also get dropped, then we can add them back at the end.

```
library(tidyverse)

map(.x = unique(names(temp)), ~ 
      select(setNames(temp, make.names(names(temp), unique = TRUE)), starts_with(.x))) %>% 
  set_names(unique(names(temp))) %>% 
  map_dfc(., rowMeans) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  `rownames<-`(row.names(temp))
```

Or another base R solution:

```
temp2 <- t(temp)
t(tapply(temp2, list(row.names(temp2)[row(temp2)], colnames(temp2)[col(temp2)]), FUN = mean))
```

**Output**

```
                   A         C         D       E       F       G
5_8S_rRNA 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000
5S_rRNA   0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.00000 2.27501 0.00000
7SK       0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000
A1BG      3.53051568 3.4409522 3.0899346 4.30520 3.68032 5.64501
A1BG-AS1  1.53633490 2.3504972 2.0157946 2.11599 1.77821 3.09930
A1CF      0.00952305 0.0285692 0.0945169 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000
```

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
library(tidyr)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
library(dplyr)

output  <- temp %>% 
  add_rownames(var = "ID") %>% 
  pivot_longer(-ID) %>% 
  mutate(name = gsub("\\.*\\d*", "", name)) %>% 
  group_by(ID, name) %>% 
  summarise(value = mean(value)) %>% 
  mutate(name = gsub("\\.*\\d*", "", name)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "name", values_from = "value")

output  
# A tibble: 6 × 7
# Groups:   ID [6]
  ID              A      C      D     E     F     G
  <chr>       <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 5_8S_rRNA 0       0      0       0     0     0   
2 5S_rRNA   0       0      0       0     2.28  0   
3 7SK       0       0      0       0     0     0   
4 A1BG      3.53    3.44   3.09    4.31  3.68  5.65
5 A1BG-AS1  1.54    2.35   2.02    2.12  1.78  3.10
6 A1CF      0.00952 0.0286 0.0945  0     0     0
```

Answer (score 2):

Using data.table

```
library('data.table')
d <- transpose(as.data.table(temp), keep.names = "rn")
d <- d[, by = rn, lapply(.SD, mean)]
d <- cbind(rn = row.names(temp), transpose(d, make.names = T))
```

Answer (score 0):

A `dplyr` + `tidyr` option using `pivot_*`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

temp %>%
  cbind(rmn = rownames(temp)) %>%
  pivot_longer(!rmn) %>%
  group_by(rmn, name) %>%
  summarise(value = mean(value), .groups = "drop") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name) %>%
  column_to_rownames("rmn")
```

gives

```
                    A          C          D        E        F        G
5_8S_rRNA 0.000000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
5S_rRNA   0.000000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.000000 2.275007 0.000000
7SK       0.000000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
A1BG      3.530515683 3.44095220 3.08993465 4.305202 3.680324 5.645010
A1BG-AS1  1.536334901 2.35049725 2.01579464 2.115993 1.778209 3.099295
A1CF      0.009523051 0.02856915 0.09451691 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
```

---

Or we can use `xtabs` a bit

```
temp %>%
  cbind(rmn = rownames(temp)) %>%
  pivot_longer(!rmn) %>%
  group_by(rmn, name) %>%
  summarise(value = mean(value), .groups = "drop") %>%
  xtabs(value ~ ., .)
```

which yields

```
           name
rmn                   A           C           D           E           F
  5_8S_rRNA 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000
  5S_rRNA   0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 2.275007047
  7SK       0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000
  A1BG      3.530515683 3.440952198 3.089934645 4.305202392 3.680324357
  A1BG-AS1  1.536334901 2.350497247 2.015794642 2.115992647 1.778208576
  A1CF      0.009523051 0.028569152 0.094516912 0.000000000 0.000000000
           name
rmn                   G
  5_8S_rRNA 0.000000000
  5S_rRNA   0.000000000
  7SK       0.000000000
  A1BG      5.645009884
  A1BG-AS1  3.099295204
  A1CF      0.000000000
```